overflow-x-auto not working in tailwind css
I have the following components that are based on the shadcn-ui Card component. The code below shows the functions:
import { evergreen } from '@/drizzle/schema';
import { InferSelectModel } from 'drizzle-orm';
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
} from '@/components/ui/card';
import { formatDateToLocal } from '@/app/lib/utils';
import { BinaryStatus, EgStatus } from './status';

type Record = InferSelectModel<typeof evergreen>;

function InfoItem({ label, value }: { label: string; value: string }) {
  return (
    <div className="space-y-1">
      <p className="text-sm font-medium leading-none text-muted-foreground">
        {label}
      </p>
      <div className="relative">
        <div className="max-w-full overflow-x-auto">
          <p className="whitespace-nowrap pr-4 text-sm font-medium">{value}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 w-8 bg-gradient-to-l from-background to-transparent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function HostCard({ record }: { record: Record }) {
  return (
    <Card className="overflow-hidden">
      <CardHeader>
        <CardTitle>Host</CardTitle>
        <CardDescription>
          Detailed description of all server information
        </CardDescription>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardContent>
        <div className="grid gap-3">
          <InfoItem label="Hostname" value={record.hostname || 'N/A'} />
          <InfoItem label="Region" value={record.region || 'N/A'} />
          <InfoItem label="Platform" value={record.platform || 'N/A'} />
          <InfoItem label="OS Version" value={record.osVersion || 'N/A'} />
          <InfoItem label="Environment" value={record.environment || 'N/A'} />
          <InfoItem label="Network" value={record.network || 'N/A'} />
          <InfoItem
            label="Shared Owners"
            value={record.sharedOwners || 'Owned by single IT service'}
          />
          <InfoItem
            label="Shared Owners Emails"
            value={record.sharedOwnersEmails || 'Owned by single IT service'}
          />
        </div>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}

function BinaryCard({ record }: { record: Record }) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader>
        <CardTitle>Binary</CardTitle>
        <CardDescription>
          Detailed description of all binary information
        </CardDescription>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardContent>
        <div className="grid gap-3">
          <InfoItem
            label="Installation Path"
            value={record.installPath || 'N/A'}
          />
        </div>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}

export function InventoryDetails({ records }: { records: Record[] }) {
  return (
    <div className="mt-10 grid gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4">
      {records.map((record) => (
        <div key={record.id} className="space-y-6">
          <HostCard record={record} />
          <BinaryCard record={record} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

The most important part is the function InfoItem, my value as in:
    <div className="max-w-full overflow-x-auto">
      <p className="whitespace-nowrap pr-4 text-sm font-medium">{value}</p>
    </div>

does not work on making the <p> tag scrollable horizontally, if I have a long string that will spill outside the Card Component.

Add a fixed width or a min-width to the content to ensure it exceeds the container's width.

You can use a class like w-24 (width of 6rem, or 96px) to ensure a fixed width for the content.


Alternatively, you can use a class like min-w-[200px] to ensure the content is at least 200px wide, triggering the horizontal scroll if it’s larger than the parent container.

